# Construction of $T^2$ and Klein bottle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology

First, don't consider the topology, I can treat the $T^2$ and Klein bottle as giving a $S^1$ at evey point of $S^1$. And the Cartesian product has nothing to topology. So $T^2=S^1\times S^1=$ Klein bottle up to set.

Second ,if the $S^1\times S^1$ carry product topology , $(U,V)$ is open if $U,V$ open, then it is $T^2$ . But  I feel that for $(U,V)\subset$Klein bottle , also 
$(U,V)$ is open if $U,V$ open . Then $T^2$ and Klein bottle have "same open set"(the words is not accurate, but I don't know how to describ it .). 
Obviously, it is wrong. Where is the mistake?

Third, if treat Klein bottle as $S^1\times S^1$ , then ,how to define its open sets making it is Klein bottle ?

Comment: Torus and Klein bottle are basically two different $S^1$ fiber bundle over $S^1$, one is orientable, and other is non-orientable.  First to get an answer try to think what is happening between Mobius strip and cylinder, that might help you to find an answer.

Comment: @Anubhav  I know the fiber of Mobius rotate ,but the cylinder don't . Klein bottle and $T^2$ are likely.  I want to know how to distinct the Klein bottle and $T^2$ from how to define the open set (or topology).

Comment: @Anubhav  Or, why they are same in local but different in global ? How to  connect the local and global to distinct the Klein bottle and $T^2$ ?

Comment: @Anubhav  Besides, I just know the definition of orientation on differentiable manifold. How to define  orientation in a topology space ?

Comment: You can use the [top homology group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_class) to define orientability for topological manifolds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're thinking too much about set theory. You should only think about the topological properties of spaces when doing topology; it's [evil](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence) to identify the underlying sets of topological spaces unless the bijection is a homeomorphism.

The Klein bottle and the Torus are both 2-manifolds, so obviously they look the same locally, and both can be given an $S^1$-bundle structure over $S^1$, so locally they are the same as fibre bundles. Note that a space is not "canonically" a bundle. A bundle is a space equipped with a projection map to a base so that it is locally trivial. A given space can be a bundle in different ways.

With regards to describing the open sets of the Klein bottle and the Torus, the most straightforward way to do it is by looking at the way they are typically constructed: as quotients of a square. The quotient construction tells you what the open sets look like.

The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle) explains how you identify the edges of the square to get a Klein bottle. Notice the difference between the identification you use to get the torus: one of the edges is given a "twist" when it is glued to the other side.

If you want to describe the $S^1$-bundle structure of the Klein bottle, what you really ought to do it is describe the [Cech cocycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle#Structure_groups_and_transition_functions) of the bundle: (an equivalence class of) open coverings of the base with transition functions that satisfy the cocycle condition. Have a look in chapter 6 of Jeffrey Lee's text on [Manifolds and Differential Geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821848151) for a good introduction to fibre bundles and how you build them from cocycles.

Comment: Thanks ,The last paragraph is good.